Is it possible to use image plane as a fill for grease pencil?
I've been trying to figure out how i can use an image as a fill for 2D animation with grease pencil, but i want to be able to texture it and add geometry nodes to the image, I thought it would be a work around to somehow draw lines with grease pencil and then the coloring would be a plane mesh with an image of fabric or something for stylization that would then have painterly texture which i thought would look cool to be made with geometry nodes and it would save a lot of time with coloring in.
Do you know any ways how i could achieve this? I was thinking masking the image inside the lines of grease pencil so it would act as a fill for example, but it just doesn't work. Would really appreciate your help!

In Grease Pencil materials you can specify to use a texture as fill, just make sure to be in preview or rendered view mode to see it.


Hey, yea i knew about this but can you use geometry nodes for the picture inside? Because i want the image to have almost like a shader and be stylized each frame.
